# WPF Keyboard Modifier on MouseBinding

Tags: wpf, checkbox, mouseevent, inputbinding

I'm working with the MVVM pattern in WPF (a bit new to both).

I'd like to set up an `InputBinding` on a `CheckBox` that corresponds to a `Control + Click` event, but do not see a `Modifiers` property on the `MouseBinding` element. This is what I'd like to achieve (fictitious code, obviously- Modifiers doesn't exist):

```
<CheckBox>
     <CheckBox.InputBindings>
           <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" 
                         Command="{Binding CheckboxControlClickCommand}"
                         Modifiers="Control" />
     </CheckBox.InputBindings>
</CheckBox>
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this without using events?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Keyboard.Modifiers in the Execute() context of the ICommand, which seemed to work just fine.

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control) return;
    ...
```

Answer (score 13):

Use it with keybinding too!

Answer (score 7):

An old question but looks like the MouseBinding now provides a Gesture attribute just for this..

```
<CheckBox>
     <CheckBox.InputBindings>
           <MouseBinding Gesture="CTRL+LeftClick" 
                         Command="{Binding CheckboxControlClickCommand}"/>
     </CheckBox.InputBindings>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a behavior would do the trick. You can take a look at [this link](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/WPFBehaviors1).

Comment: I don't think you're off-base; I could have used a behavior but didn't know that I could check the Keyboard.Modifiers in the Execute() context of the ICommand, which is what I ended up doing.