# WPF Proper Click Event

Tags: .net, wpf

How do I implement a proper click event handler in WPF.  What I mean by that is mouseDown, mouseUp, on the same object, without moving the cursor off the object, with which button was used (left, right, center, 4th or 5th button).  The click event has the basic behavior, but only works on the left mouse button.

I guess I could customize code to pull the mouse down, mouse up, mouse pointer exits events, create a derived class that tracks these states, but this seems a lot of work for what is normally such a standard event handler.

Comment: Could you please describe more of your current scenario. Which component type do you want to be able to click at?

Comment: In WPF you usually define which action triggers a given Command. For that, you can use `MouseBinding` with `Gestures`. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667707/wpf-keyboard-modifier-on-mousebinding

Comment: It doesn't really matter what component type.  Any component type that could do this.