# How to make binding of CheckBox.InputBindings MouseBinding to a command in viewmodel, instead of DataGrid object item?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a problem with binding `LeftClick` MouseAction to the `Command`. I found in **SO** loads of examples about command binding to the viewmodel, but not similar like mine. Mine seems to quite unique due to context binding inside of my `WindowManager` service.

I already tried approaches:

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44301665)
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4500947/12603542)
- `{Binding Path=Window.DataContext.SelectedCountCommand}`

All of them gave me:

> Binding expression path error: ('DataContext' / 'Window' / 'SelectedCountCommand') property not found on
> 'object' CheckedProject (...)

My window data binding happens in my **WindowManager** service, where I am binding DataContext as follws:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Creates instance of new window basing on window type, returns new instance of WindowModel object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">Window type</param>
        /// <param name="viewModel">View model related to the window</param>
        /// <returns>WindowModel object</returns>
        private WindowModel GetWindowModelFromWindowName(Type type, object viewModel)
        {
            Window window = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            window.DataContext = viewModel;

            //some model instance stuff here

            return model;
        }
```

And I am not able to use in my **xaml** anything like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:ViewModelName/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

And my checkbox, that I try to do a `MouseBinding` for him, is inside of `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Check" Width="50">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <CheckBox.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedCountCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
                                </CheckBox.InputBindings>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How to binde it to `SelectedCountCommand` inside of my viewmodel, instead of `DataGrid` item, where `CheckedProject` is an type of ObservableCollection item, that DataGrid` is binded to?

**UPDATE:**
I am getting same exception when using `EventTrigger` on CheckBoxes:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCountCommand}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCountCommand}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is within the datagrid template column, the context will be the DataGridRow. Your service is setting the datacontext for the window and we have to bind the command to the window datacontext.

Try :

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType= {x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedCountCommand}"
```

If your command expects command parameters, you may need to supply them as required.

Comment: Actually it works, with one difference, instead of `{x:Type Window}` I have `{x:Type DataGrid}`